# Empty Pathname is not legal

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

This code works when inserting data together with image in a database. The problem is when i do not put an image in the `PictureBox`. It gives me error:

> Empty Pathname is not legal in line 3

What i want is even the user do not have pictures selected. The other data will be inserted and will not give error.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudFN.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudLN.Text  
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StudPic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
```

Comment: assign `DBNull.Value` if you have no image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `DBNull.Value` if you have no image.

For example if `a.FileName` is the image file name, you can use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudPic", SqlDbType.Image))
If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Name) AndAlso System.IO.File.Exists(a.FileName)) Then
    cmd.Parameters("@StudPic").Value = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
Else
    cmd.Parameters("@StudPic").Value = DBNull.Value
End If
```